# PHP - Get a values from a multidimentional array and appending them as a string

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, loops

I'm trying to pluck a value from a multidimensional (I think that's the term) array and append it to a string variable. It's a POST to Laravel from a JSON array.

The array:

```
0:
  icon: "nanny"
  name: "Nanny"
  order: 1
  price: 3000
  selected: true

1:
  icon: "driver"
  name: "Driver"
  order: 3
  price: 2000
  selected: true
```

I want to get the value of name and append it to a variable as a string.

`$items = 'Nanny, Driver, '`

This is my attempt

```
$items = '';

foreach($request->services as $service) {
    foreach ($service as $key => $value) {
        $items .= $key['name'] . ', ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you can remove one of the foreach loops, like `$items = ''; foreach($request->services as $service) { $items .= $service['name']; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$key` is the key, you want the value, and you only want the value for `"name"`. Regardless, we can do this in one line:

```
$items = implode(', ', array_column($request->services, 'name'));
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: FYI if using Laravel, it has a method called `pluck()` which does a similar job to `array_column()`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-pluck